# How to Use an HTML editor / Wysiwyg with vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

Just starting to use vuetify - really good stuff.

How can I wire up an HTML editor like quilljs.

I saw this post here; https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3550

Ideally.. I would like to use them both in codepen so I can get a designer to work on some bits and piece.

suggestions?

Answer (score 15):

I created an editor for Vuetify based on Tiptap: https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/tiptap-vuetify

It is planned to make it as flexible as possible and develop many plugins for it.

[image]

You can support by giving a star to motivate me to develop.

Comment: @wobsoriano development is already underway, I will release as soon as possible

Comment: @wobsoriano done, now there is support for Vuetify 2!

Comment: That is awesome. I'll try it. Thank you.